# how to implement button with backgroundimage programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I'm developing images in view with button programmatically in iphone. now I want to add button backgroundimage for next and previous buttons. I want to add a images for these buttons programmatically.

how to add button image in iphone.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

// Add the button like this

```
UIImage *redButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ExitButton.png"];

        UIButton *redButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        redButton.frame = CGRectMake(280.0, 10.0, 29.0, 29.0);
        [redButton setBackgroundImage:redButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [view addSubview:redButton];
```

Answer (score 8):

you can try this

```
 UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];


//create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
//UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickActionItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

good luck

Answer (score 4):

use this for setting image in you button

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:yourImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
UIButton *yourButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40);
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroungImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view yourButton];
```